# Android Button: Displaying black square and not img?

Tags: android, button

I have a rather small but weird problem that I can't seem to fix.
I am trying to display a  image for my button, and it's showing up as a black square.
The buttons I made before this are showing up and working fine, but this button (and the rest I make afterwards) are showing up as black squares..
Now if I change it to a ImageView instead of a Button, it displays fine.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? If so how did you solve it? 
I'm still pretty novice to programming and I'm teaching myself so I really don't have any help and I've been trying to fix it for awhile now. :(

Here is the xml for the button/image.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:src="@drawable/pause"

            android:layout_width="29px"
            android:layout_height="29px"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
        </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you have any other questions please ask, and thanks a ton for viewing my problem! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use an `ImageButton` instead of `Button` or change `android:src="@drawable/pause"` to  `android:background="@drawable/pause"`